# How to change Title Textcolor of 1 character in NavigationController in iOS using Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uicolor, navigationbar

I am trying to change the title text color from the navigationbar in iOS using Xamarin.

I know how to change the whole color of the title of the navigationbar.
See my current code below.

```
this.title = "Hello 2 all of you";
this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.TitleTextAttributes = new UIStringAttributes()
{               
    ForegroundColor = UIColor.White
};
```

But is it possible to put the "2" in my title in Orange and the rest of the title in white?
How could i solve this problem?

This is what i would like to achieve:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLszW.jpg

Thnx for your help!

Answer (score 2):

@Hobeau helped me to find an answer.
If any needs the answer. Here it is.

```
var firstAttributes = new UIStringAttributes {
    ForegroundColor = UIColor.White,
    BackgroundColor = UIColor.Black,
    Font = UIFont.FromName("Arial", 24f)
};

    var secondAttributes = new UIStringAttributes {
        ForegroundColor = UIColor.Orange,
        BackgroundColor = UIColor.Black,
        Font = UIFont.FromName("Arial", 24f)
    };


    var prettyString = new NSMutableAttributedString ("Hello 2 all of you");
    prettyString.SetAttributes (firstAttributes.Dictionary, new NSRange (0, 6));
    prettyString.SetAttributes (secondAttributes.Dictionary, new NSRange (6, 1));
    prettyString.SetAttributes (firstAttributes.Dictionary, new NSRange (7, 11));

    testlbl.AttributedText = prettyString;
    this.NavigationItem.TitleView = testlbl;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. Have been searching for about 3 hours until I found your answer.